# Grab text from HTML using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following HTML on my web page.

Is it possible to use PHP (or jQuery) to grab the content within the divs? I'd ultimately like to use it within a PHP script.

```
<div id="selectedaddress">
    <div>James</div>
    <div>Thomson</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>England</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use the `DOMDocument` class to parse HTML and extract content.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of tags use `strip_tags()`

Comment: @ponury-kostek That's an excellent point - I might investigate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this

```
$('#selectedaddress').children().each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[see console on jsfiddle - working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xfqc4mvs/)

Answer (score 2):

Possible another easy way using `map()`

```js
  $("#selectedaddress div").map(function(x,e){
   alert($(e).text());
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectedaddress">
        <div>
            James
        </div>
        <div>
            Thomson
        </div>
        <div>
            London
        </div>
        <div>
            England
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what functionality you are looking for. Judging by the code you have, most likely you want a `<form>` with `<input>` tags and a submit button.

For a form functionality, check out [PHP 5 Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_forms.asp) and [The `<select>` element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp). You would like to grab a value from a selected list.